# How to do auto login in python with sql database?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

how can I make a login form that will remember the user so that he does not have to log in next time.

Comment: You can set a cookie that does not expire when the browser is closed.

Comment: I wish it was an application written purely as a separate program without the use of a browser

Comment: If it is a desktop app,thenyou need to create the equivalent of a cookie (place a file at a certain location with a content that identifies the user and that the password has already been entered correctly.). Or use some kind of a SSO solution.

Comment: You can store the login status in the SQL database.  Better have an expiry date on the login status.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information would be nice but if you want to use a database for this then you would have to create a entry for the user information last entered.

And then on reopening the programm you would check if there are any entrys and if yes load it.

But I think that writing the login information to a file on you pc would be a lot easier. So you run the steps from above just writing to a file instead of a database.

I am not sure how you would make this secure because you can't really encrypt the password because you would need a password or key of some type and that password or key would be easy to find in the source code especially in python. It would be harder to find in other compiler based programming languages but also somewhere. And if you would use a database you would have a password for that but that would also lay on the hardrive if not encrypted otherwise but there we are where we started.

So as mentioned above a database would be quite useless for a task like this because it doesn't improve anything and is a hassle for beginners to setup.

Comment: A solution such as retrieving information from a local file is not very good for security reasons, you can finally try to encrypt this data, but it is so unpleasant that it would be a lot of fun with it. Maybe there's a faster way